# tex '\empty Hello world!\bye' found not found

Tags: latex, evince

After doing a [minimal installation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation#Minimal_installation) of TeX I try to open the .dvi file generated with the [command](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation#First_test):

```
tex '\empty Hello world!\bye'
```

and I get the following output:

```
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /etc/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c.

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktexpk: Permiso denegado
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
page: Warning: font `cmr10' not found, trying metric files instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmr10
mkofm: Permiso denegado

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10
mktextfm: Permiso denegado
page: Error: could not load font `cmr10'

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktexpk: Permiso denegado
page: Warning: font `cmr10' not found, trying metric files instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmr10
mkofm: Permiso denegado

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10
mktextfm: Permiso denegado
page: Error: could not load font `cmr10'
```

Comment: Possibly related to [Problem opening .dvi files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46764/65304)?

Comment: xdiv worked but I couldn't make evince work with the fix explained in the bug report. I added the line

/usr/local/texlive/** rux,

to my /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.evince but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you restart the apparmor service in order to reload your changes? e.g. `sudo service apparmor restart`

Comment: I did `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart` and says stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy texlive-base`